# Apply a new mongoose middleware pre-condition to all already existing elements in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose I just added a pre condition to an existing model. This condition basically concatenate the values of all elements in the object, creates a hash and store it as another field in the same object.
This code will be executed on all elementes I will save from now on, but I was wondering if is possible to execute it also to all existing elements or if I have to write a script that updates them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The records in your database will not be magically updated, you will have to update them manually for the first time.

If your new middleware works with updates you could find all your records and just save them. The middleware will be used and the new field will be populated.

Something like:

```
Model.find({}, function(err, records) {
    records.forEach(function(record) {
        record.save(function(err) { console.log(err); });
    });
}
```

This will however be slow if your database is huge. In this case will be better updating the database directly.

Comment: well then, lucky me is not big at all. thanks for the answer, is exactly how I expected to be